# Error to remove openSUSE repository

Tags: linux, opensuse, repository, zypper

I'm using `OpenSUSE Leap` with `Gnome`

I trying remove a repository to fix a error, but haven't had any success

When I type `sudo zypper ls` is returning for me:

```
sudo zypper ls
# | Alias   | Name    | Enabled | GPG Check | Refresh | Type
--+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----
1 | service | service | Yes     | ----      | Yes     | ris
```

But when I try remove this repository `sudo zypper rr 1`:

```
sudo zypper rr 1
Repository '1' not found by alias, number or URI.
```

Or `sudo zypper rr service`:

```
sudo zypper rr service
Repository 'service' not found by alias, number or URI.
```

Following my `/etc/zypp/repos.d`:

```
/etc/zypp/repos.d> ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Apr 10 10:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 200 Apr  8 22:50 ..
```

Why can I not remove `service`? how to can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use `zypper lr` to list repositories, `ls` lists services. Or, if you really want to remove the service, use `rs` instead of `rr`.

Comment: I don't know why occur this problem, but I fix it removing `service 'service'` using `sudo zypper rs service`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know my solution can be any problem future, but is a solution for me now

I just remove `service 'service'` using fallowing command:

```
sudo zypper rs service
```